# Simple parallelization of subprocess.run() calls?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Consider the following snippet that runs three different subprocesses one after the other with `subprocess.run` (and notably all with defaulted kwargs):

```
import subprocess

p1 = subprocess.run(args1)
if p1.returncode != 0:
   error()
p2 = subprocess.run(args2)
if p2.returncode != 0:
   error()
p3 = subprocess.run(args3)
if p3.returncode != 0:
   error()
```

How can we rewrite this so that the subprocesses are run in parallel to each other?

With `Popen` right?  What does that exactly look like?

For reference, the implementation of `subprocess.run` is essentially:

```
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    try:
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
    except TimeoutExpired as exc:
        process.kill()
        if _mswindows:
            exc.stdout, exc.stderr = process.communicate()
        else:
            process.wait()
        raise
    except:
        process.kill()
        raise
    retcode = process.poll()
return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)
```

So something like...

```
with Popen(args1) as p1:
    with Popen(args2) as p2:
        with Popen(args3) as p3:
            try:
                p1.communicate(None, timeout=None)
                p2.communicate(None, timeout=None)
                p3.communicate(None, timeout=None)
            except:
                p1.kill()
                p2.kill()
                p3.kill()
                raise
            if p1.poll() != 0 or p2.poll() != 0 or p3.poll() != 0:
                error()
```

Is that along the right lines?

Comment: So I'm not sending any input or collecting any output (or at least the output is going to the default place), so I guess I don't even need to call `communicate` ?  And I guess `poll` is wrong maybe it should be `wait` instead?  It's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use multiprocessing to accomplish your mission but ensuring that your invocation of `subprocess.run` uses `capture_output=True` so that the output from the 3 commands running in parallel are not interlaced:

```
import multiprocessing
import subprocess


def runner(args):
    p = subprocess.run(args, capture_output=True, text=True)
    if p.returncode != 0:
        raise Exception(r'Return code was {p.returncode}.')
    return p.stdout, p.stderr

def main():
    args1 = ['git', 'status']
    args2 = ['git', 'log', '-3']
    args3 = ['git', 'branch']
    args = [args1, args2, args3]
    with multiprocessing.Pool(3) as pool:
        results = [pool.apply_async(runner, args=(arg,)) for arg in args]
        for result in results:
            try:
                out, err = result.get()
                print(out, end='')
            except Exception as e: # runner completed with an Exception
                print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__': # required for Windows
    main()
```

**Update**

With just `subprocess` we have something like:

```
import subprocess


args1 = ['git', 'status']
args2 = ['git', 'log', '-3']
args3 = ['git', 'branch']

p1 = subprocess.Popen(args1)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(args2)
p3 = subprocess.Popen(args3)

p1.communicate()
rc1 = p1.returncode
p2.communicate()
rc2 = p2.returncode
p3.communicate()
rc3 = p3.returncode
```

But, for whatever reason on my Windows platform I never saw the output from the third subprocess command ('git branch'), so there must be some limitation there. Also, if the command you were running required input from stdin before proceeding, that input would have to be provided to the `communicate` method. But the communicate method would not complete until the entire subprocess has completed and you would get no parallelism, so as a general solution this is not really very good. In the multiprocessing code, there is no problem with having stdin input to `communicate`.

**Update 2**

When I recode it as follows, I now get all the expected output. I am not sure why it makes a difference, however. According to the documentation, `Popen.communicate`:

> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate and set the returncode attribute. The optional input argument should be data to be sent to the child process, or None, if no data should be sent to the child. If streams were opened in text mode, input must be a string. Otherwise, it must be bytes.

So the call should be waiting for the process to terminate. Nevertheless, my preceding comment about the situation where the command you are executing requiring stdin input (via a pipe) would not run in parallel without using multiprocessing.

```
import subprocess


args1 = ['git', 'status']
args2 = ['git', 'log', '-3']
args3 = ['git', 'branch']

with subprocess.Popen(args1) as p1:
    with subprocess.Popen(args2) as p2:
        with subprocess.Popen(args3) as p3:
            p1.communicate()
            rc1 = p1.returncode
            p2.communicate()
            rc2 = p2.returncode
            p3.communicate()
            rc3 = p3.returncode
```

Comment: Certainly an interesting idea, but isn't there a simpler way to do it just within `subprocess`?  or is the problem that the global interpretter lock gets in the way?  What's the benefit of using the `multiprocessing` module in addition to `subprocess`?

Comment: Are you checking the `returncode`s are zero in the real example?  Perhaps something went wrong within the subprocess of git branch on the first run.  Not clear why `subprocess.run` is calling `.poll`, but from the documentation couldn't you (or shouldn't you) call `.wait` instead of `.communicate`.

Comment: More info: Popens `__exit__` calls `.wait()` - could explain the difference of using a with statement

Comment: I tried printing out the return code and it was 0. The documentation says `communicate` waits for the process to terminate and I have always used that method, albeit never have I tried to have more than one `Popen` in effect at a time (except in the multiprocessing case as I have demonstrated). I have tried rerunning my first Update code and now it seems to be putting out all three outputs. I have no explanation. Maybe I am crazy. Anyway, look at all the examples given in the documentation, which do not use a context manager (i.e. `with` block) and do use`communicate`.

Comment: Anyway, consider using pipes for stdout and stderr to avoid output from being interlaced.